# dotnet publish Not Deploying

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, .net-core-2.0

I am trying to execute a Web Deploy on my .NET Core 2.0 Project. Deploying manually from within Visual Studio's "Publish" feature works fine.

From the command line, I am executing:

`dotnet publish TechsportiseOnline/TechsportiseOnline.csproj -c Release /p:PublishProfile="Properties\PublishProfiles\techsportise.com - Web Deploy" /p:Username="***" /p:Password="***"`

The command comes back as successful, with no errors at all - even with verbosity set to Diagnostic. For all intents and purposes, Visual Studio thinks its been a success.

However when I visit the website, the change I have made is very clearly not there. I have tried visiting Incognito and clearing cache and the change simply is not deployed.

I have tried the same command using `dotnet build /p:DeployOnBuild=true` and I have also tried specifying all the parameters manually

`dotnet build TechsportiseOnline/TechsportiseOnline.csproj -c Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployIisPath="techsportise.com" /p:MSDeployServiceURL="***" /p:Username="***" /p:Password="***" /p:SkipExtraFilesOnServer=true /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true`

I don't think its a local system issue as I am getting the same issue using Bitbucket Pipelines - reporting success even though no changes are visible post-deploy. I don't think it's a server issue as it works when manually executing Publish inside VS.

Any ideas?

Comment: "Visual Studio thinks its been a success" - this is unlikely. More likely Visual Studio simply does not know anything about it, since it's not involved in the process. Similarly, if you set verbosity to Diagnostic in Visual Studio, your command line process is not aware of it.

Comment: That a very good point. In which case what I mean is, the command line logs do not throw an error to indicate it has not been successful.

Comment: i think you should restart IIS AppPool to see the change.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for changes using the web browser. Instead verify the files have changed. I am assuming they have and your issue it the browser is caching the website. Try refreshing with `ctr + F5` or try clearing the browser data.

Answer (score 0):

Either you are executing the command from a different folder which has the same project files or you have some Cache issues. Try Ctrl+shift+delete on your browser and clear everything or open a new Incognito window and try again.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread - but I found there is a bug w/ dotnet publish when using CLI.

It'll ignore the `PublishUrl` and publish locally (can view from the logs pretty easily)

To get around - you can manually add `PublishDir` then it'll work from the CLI

https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/12490